# Make a button visible after a PHP script has been executed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, passwords

Hi all I have a requirement to make an add items button visible once the user has logged in im trying to test this with the below test code but am not sure of the best way to make a button visible after a php call any help would be appreciated.

passwordchecker.php

```
<?php
        $message = "access granted, you can now add items";
        $message1 = "access denied";
    $user = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        if ($user == "admin" && $pass == "admin")
        {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
          alert('$message');
          </script>";
        die();
        }
        else
        {
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
          alert('$message1');
          </script>";
              die();
        }
?>
```

button we are trying to display

```
<a href="#AddItems" class="btn btn-default btn-lg history" style="visibility:hidden" id="additems">Add item</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated usually I would use Jquery to show and hide buttons but i'm not sure if this is possible in the current situation or if it is the best way to handle it.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use Session variables to check authentication.
Basically, you can be done this without any javascript
simply

```
if ($user == "admin" && $pass == "admin") 
    { 
       ?>
        <a href="#AddItems" class="btn btn-default btn-lg history" style="visibility:hidden" id="additems">Add item</a>
      <?php
      }
```

or if you want to use jQuery

Add item

```
<?php 
    if ($user == "admin" && $pass == "admin") 
        { 
         ?>
           <script>
               $( document ).ready(function() {
                  $('#additems').show();
                  alert(<?php echo $message;?>); 
               });
            </script>
          <?php
          } else {
              <script>
               $( document ).ready(function() {
                  alert(<?php echo $message1;?>); 
               });
            </script>
          }
```

using sessions is the best practice for authentication so use

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) instead of if ($user == "admin" && $pass == "admin")
```

after setting $_SESSION['user'] in login or somewhere you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Just add it in your PHP like this (if the user exists echo the button else dont.)

```
<?php
    $message = "access granted, you can now add items";
    $message1 = "access denied";
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    if ($user == "admin" && $pass == "admin")
    {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
      alert('$message');
      </script>'
      <a href=\"#AddItems\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-lg history\" style=\"visibility:hidden\" id=\"additems\">Add item</a>";
    die();
    }
    else
    {
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
      alert('$message1');
      </script>";
          die();
    }
?>
```